# background image not loading in a div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have created a page in React where I was using `<Image...>` to load an image as a header.

Instead of this, I would like to replace `<Image..>` by using the `<div backgroundImage...>`

So I have done the code below, and move from :

```html
<div className="class-details-header">
    <div className="class-details-header">
        <img src={ this.state.headerImage } 
             alt="VillageHeader" 
             className="class-details-image" />
    </div>
</div>
```

To:

```html
<div className="class-details-header" style={{ backgrounImage: `url(${this.state.headerImage})`}}>
    <p> Any Text </p>
</div>
```

but nothing is displayed.

here is the css:

```css
.class-details-header {
    width: 70% ;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: 100% 100% no-repeat;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

the first method works as the image was loaded and displayed. but once I move to background, it's not showing up.

this is the image : https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/16/23/10/spice-370114_1280.jpg

any idea why bkg is not working when img work ?

thanks

Comment: I think you'd need to do something like on the `<div>` `style={{ backgroundImage: `url("${this.state.headerImage}")`

Comment: @Anthony sorry I forgot a part of the code. please check now

Comment: you have `backgrounImage` instead of `backgroundImage` in your sample, and also missing the double quotes `"` in `url()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though you have a few typos in your script.

Firstly, when you were implementing your `backgroundImage` style you missed the *d*, therefore making it `backgrounImage`.

Secondly, in the `url` function, you missed the double quotes, so instead of it being:

`` backgroundImage: `url("${this.state.headerImage}")` ``, it's

`` backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.headerImage})` ``.

Those are the two problems in your code and correcting them should fix it.